# Bucles y Estructuras de Datos Python - Duda Bucle

Tags: python

**Hola. Llevo más de un mes intentando resolver un ejercicio para un curso de iniciación a la programación en Python. El enunciado dice así:**

"Escribe un programa que te ayude a llevar un registro de tus gastos. El programa te hará 3 preguntas para cada gasto: el motivo, el lugar y la cantidad. Tras cada gasto introducido, el programa te preguntará si quieres introducir otro gasto más. Al finalizar, el programa debe imprimir todos los gastos en el mismo orden que los introdujiste y la cantidad total de dinero gastado. La información de cada gasto la debes almacenar como un diccionario con 3 claves de tipo cadena: motivo, lugar y cantidad. Para almacenar la secuencia de gastos debes usar una lista. Es decir, la estructura de datos que almacena la información es una lista donde cada elemento es un diccionario."

**El ejercicio además me dice que el programa debería ejecutarse así:**

Quieres introducir más gastos (si/no): si

Motivo del gasto: camiseta

Lugar del gasto: El Corte Inglés

Cantidad gastada: 15

Quieres introducir más gastos (si/no): si

Motivo del gasto: fruta

Lugar del gasto: mercado

Cantidad gastada: 20

Quieres introducir más gastos (si/no): no

Gastos:

camiseta en El Corte Inglés : 15.0 euros

fruta en mercado : 20.0 euros

Cantidad total : 35.0 euros

**y que la estructura del código debería corresponderse con este esquema:**

crear lista de gastos vacía

preguntar al usuario si quiere introducir más gastos

mientras haya más gastos

```
pedir datos del gasto al usuario

crear diccionario con la información del gasto

añadir el diccionario a la lista de gastos

preguntar al usuario si quiere introducir más gastos
```

cantidad_total = 0

para cada gasto en la lista de gastos:

```
imprimir información del gasto

acumular la cantidad del gasto en cantidad_total
```

imprimir cantidad_total

**Yo le he enviado este código a mi profesor:**

expenselist = []

expense = input('¿Desea introducir más gastos?')

totalexpense = 0

while expense == 'si':

```
expenses = {}
expenses['Motivo del gasto'] = input('Motivo del gasto: ')
expenses['Lugar del gasto'] = input('Lugar del gasto: ')
expenses['Cantidad gastada'] = float(input('Cantidad gastada: '))
expenselist.append(expenses)
expense = input('¿Desea introducir más gastos?')

totalexpense = totalexpense + expenses['Cantidad gastada']
print(expenses['Cantidad gastada'])
print(totalexpense)
```

*(No sé cómo hacer que se vea igual que en mi programa de Pycharm)*

**Al ejecutarlo, consigo sumar los valores de los gastos introducidos pero no me aparecen como me pide el enunciado y mi profesor no me da el ejercicio por "apto" diciendo que: "Necesitas dos bucles, uno para almacenar la información en la lista y otro para mostrar la información de los gastos en el mismo formato que aparece en el enunciado."**

**Llevo bastante tiempo dándole vueltas a lo del segundo bucle (porque entiendo que el primero, el de almacenar la información en la lista, ya está en mi código) pero por mis limitados conocimientos de Python, no logro dar con la solución.**

**Muchas gracias por su ayuda**

Answer (score 0):

Si no te he entendido mal, creo que lo que tu profesor quiere decir con el segundo bucle para mostrar la información es lo siguiente: como tienes los valores almacenados en un diccionario, puedes recorrerlo así:

```
valores = expenses.values()

for valor in valores:
    print(valores)
```

Un saludo y bienvenido